# Symptoms of bad camber?

Tags: suspension, alignment, escape

My car's steering is unpredictable at times. It often happens when going over a bump or turning or on a road with a lot of droops in it. For just a split second the steering will go in a direction I didn't tell it to and shortly after it will recover. Sometimes it goes back and forth and steering feels totally uncontrollable for a few minor swerves.

I have tried a lot of things to fix it:

- had front tires replaced
- switched out really bad rear tire with okay front tire
- replaced rear shock (which just so happened to come loose while I've been working on this)
- replaced both control arms (with new ball joints)
- replace one of the tie rod ends
- did a front end alignment (only set toe)
- topped off power steering fluid

I did all that and the problem is still there. I don't have the proper device but I used a level to get an approximation and I believe the camber on the passenger side is way off. So I am gong to get some camber adjustment bolts tomorrow and try them.

Does that sound reasonable to you? I'm running out of things to check. I hope it's not the steering rack.

Comment: You switched a poor tire from the front for a really bad rear one? Why not fit a good set of tires all round and re-evaluate?

Comment: This symptom doesn't sound like a camber issue.  It sounds more like a worn component.  You said you changed one tie rod end, what about the other one?  What about your wheel bearings?  What about your steering gear?

Comment: Other tie rod end looked and felt good. Wheel bearing make no grinding noise and turn freely and are firmly seated. As for my steering gear you mean the "pinion", right? If so, idk. I haven't checked that. That seems like a lot of work.

Comment: I mean "is there play in the steering system?"  If there is, then that may be the source of your problem.  But regardless, I don't think camber is the problem.  Go ahead and adjust it if you think it will help, however.

Comment: finally found the answer to this. the passenger side ball joint wasn't tightened down enough.